# Making site facilities more obvious to the average user - mainly but not restricted to 'chat'

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

Finding this Meta is a challenge in itself. Many users don't know of its existence (anecdotal evidence only). I only found my way here by guesswork. I Googled ***stack exchange meta***

However, for the purposes of this question I'd like to focus on "chat"

I discovered its existence by being diverted there from a too-long discussion.  When I wanted to return to chat I searched all over the place. Eventually someone pointed me to its location. A small and insignificant tag in the menu at top left.

**Question**

1. Is there a case for redesigning the front pages to make access to frequently used services obvious? I am aware that such a task takes time and resources.
2. How come I can't find something as important as chat in the Help Center? It offers 'Detailed answers to any questions you might have". When I search for chat it gives me *0 results*.
3. Have others experienced difficulty in finding their way around. Assuming of course that the experienced users most likely to see this question can remember that far back! ;-)

Comment: The thing is, chat is **not**  frequently used. Only very minor part of the overall users use it, and honestly it's for the best. Those who want will find it.

Comment: I suggest that it's little used because most people don't know how to use it. Could you explain why 'it's for the best'? I can't guess your reasoning.

Comment: Because it will flood the chat rooms with "plz giv me tha codez" messages, for a start. But seriously now, it takes 20 reputation to be able to take part in chat. 99% of the new users don't have it, so link to chat will be just noise/teasing for them

Comment: Hmm. http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat

Comment: Note that searching in help pages seems to be currently broken. [The search functionality of the Help pages isn't working](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302130)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thanks. I presume your 'Hmm' means that I should have found the page easily. Here was my procedure: - Help>Help Center>Search 'chat'.  Result zilch. How did you get there? - Update - I've just seen your follow-up comment.

Comment: I knew where to look ("Note that searching in help pages seems to be currently broken")

Comment: @chaslyfromUK You would have received a notification about the chat privilege when you got 20 rep.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Forgive me but that seems to be an elitist argument. 'Others will misuse it'.  If you want to avoid trivial usage then simply make the necessary reputation 100, or 200 or 2000.  In my experience is not out of the question to have blanked out or invisible tabs on a front page that can be activated when the user reaches the required level.

Comment: Maybe it sounds elitist, but after seeing the level of questions from new users for enough time, it's just being realistic.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "Finding this Meta is a challenge in itself." Every SE site has a "help" > "Meta" menu item ...

Comment: @ShadowWizard - and my suggestion to simply make the reputation requirement higher? The great thing about SE is that it provides a (quite harsh) training ground for users. It is an effective filter against the type of people who pester with 'plz tell me'.  Raising the requirement automatically raises the standard.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I quickly found the Meta for ELU where I first joined.  The same for other communities. It's this one that doesn't have a non-meta that's difficult to find. I had to divine its existence by using my experience of how developers' minds work.

Comment: @DavidPostill "*You would have received a notification*". I certainly did. It was finding the damn thing in order to *use* it  that stumped me! :-) I think Help must have been OoO for some time.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK As far as I know only since the move to Denver ... 3 days ago

Answer (score 4):

> A small and insignificant tag in the menu at top left.

To be fair, that "insignificant" tag is in the site's *main menu*. It's fairly important area and is prominent.

> Is there a case for redesigning the front pages to make access to
>   frequently used services obvious?

Possibly yes, but you'll have to be more specific. But not for chat.

The site has a *great deal* of functionality, and fitting it all in the prime spots is impossible. Also, if you just start moving things around, you just *move the issue* and at some point someone is not going to be able to find something they want.

The site places the "most used" and "most important" things prominently.

> Finding this Meta is a challenge in itself. Many users don't know of
>   its existence (anecdotal evidence only). I only found my way here by
>   guesswork.

The site's navigation areas are pretty simple, and uncluttered.

On the top bar (black bar) to the right you have "Help".
If you are looking for support, or "help", then the "Help" option up the top would be logical, which is on every single page.

That dropdown has links to the "help center" and "Meta", which resolves your "can't find meta" issue.

That said, I do appreciate it can be a little daunting sometimes finding things - truly, I still find things now and go "Ooh, that's where that is".

However, I'm not sure how the site could better arranges things. I think the confusion and difficulty in finding some things (sometimes) is just because the sites have a lot of functionality, and so it does take a little getting used to and learning where the major things are like links to the help center, Metas, etc.

---

> Have others experienced difficulty in finding their way around.
>   Assuming of course that the experienced users most likely to see this
>   question can remember that far back! ;-)

I remember that far back, and I do understand fully that there is a fair bit to learn, more than long term users remember.

Long term users should especially consider that since they were new, there has been a lot of new functions added, and thus links and pages to cater for the new functionality, and more help center pages, more Meta questions to search and rake through, etc.

So long term users have the advantage that previous things have already been learned, and a lot of the new things over the years (since they joined) have been *built up around them* - and not like a new user coming to them *all at once* without a clue about any of it.

---

### CHAT

> How come I can't find something as important as chat in the Help
>   Center? It offers 'Detailed answers to any questions you might have".
>   When I search for chat it gives me 0 results.

I think the Help Center is a little bugged ATM, so that won't always be the case. You were just unlucky.

That said, I'm all for new users going to chat and asking question that might not fit on any site, or wanting to "chatter" a little more than is possible or practical in the Q&A area.
However, I also agree with [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263484/making-site-facilities-more-obvious-to-the-average-user-mainly-but-not-restric#comment857071_263484), in that we don't want all users flocking there, as then rather than users willing to find it who likely ask a decent question, it just gets flooded with *everyone*, and then no-one can see the wood for the trees.

And for the 99% of the time, questions belong on the main site in a question, as then more people can help, the site returns the question and answers in searches, as with Google, and so more people get help from that question.

I know this sounds like chat is a private little area, but it is not that. You are welcome, as is anyone, it would just spoil it if all the new and "lazy" users come there because it's *much easier* to write in chat than spending time typing out a good question.

Chat is listed in the main site dropdown, in the privileges and badges areas, and other areas around the site.
So specifically, chat is not "hidden" it's just "not advertised".

> If you want to avoid trivial usage then simply make the necessary
>   reputation 100, or 200 or 2000.

You are arguing against yourself :)
On one hand you argue that everyone should have access to chat and it not be limited to some "select few", but then suggest some unfair limit.
Why should users with less 100 or 200 rep not be allowed in chat?
The current 20 rep limit is just to stop *absolutely* new users flooding there and spamming all sorts of questions which would be fine on the Q&A side with a bit of effort.

Comment: @Shadow:  s-h-a-m-e-l-e-s-s self promotion! :D (sorry, I should have done that :) )

Comment: lol, was going to just fix my name (you forgot a space!) then on second thought also added context. ;)

Comment: Yeah no worries. (I used no space because it's a username, but I actually hope that's actually your *real* name)

Comment: Won't it be cool to have people actually refer to you as "Mr. Wizard"? :-D

Comment: It would, but my grin was from thinking everyone calling me "Shadow"

Comment: lol, actually there's [something like that for real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shadow_(rapper)). (no relation to me ;-))